# difference between /dev/input/mouse0 and /dev/input/mice

Tags: mouse, input-devices

I'm working with a mouse USB driver and I really don't know how to differenciate and use information send by `/dev/input/mouse0` and `/dev/input/mice`

After few searches on Google, I found this code about using `/dev/input/mice`

```
int fd, bytes;
unsigned char data[4];

const char *pDevice = "/dev/input/mice";

// Open Mouse
fd = open(pDevice, O_RDWR);
if(fd == -1)
{
    printf("ERROR Opening %s\n", pDevice);
    return -1;
}

int left, middle, right;
signed char x, y;

// Read Mouse
bytes = read(fd, data, sizeof(data));

if(bytes > 0)
{
    left = data[0] & 0x1;
    right = data[0] & 0x2;
    middle = data[0] & 0x4;

    x = data[1];
    y = data[2];
    printf("x=%d, y=%d, left=%d, middle=%d, right=%d\n", x, y, left, middle, right);

    if(left)
        return left;
    if(right)
        return right;
    if(middle)
        return middle;
}

return 0;
```

This program works but didn't get any information about the wheel scroll.

I was able to find a program which uses `/dev/input/event0`

```
int fd;
struct input_event ev
const char* pFile = "/dev/input/event0";

fd = open(pFile, O_RDONLY);
if(fd == -1)
{
    printf("ERROR Opening %s\n", pFile);are
    return -1;
}

read(fd, &ev, sizeof(ev));
std::cout << "type : " << ev.type << "  code : " << ev.code << "  value : " << ev.value << std::endl;

close(fd);

return 0;
```

But there is a problem for diagonal movement because this file saved only 1 coordinate at the same time, and the X coordinate has priority over the Y, so it's pretty annoying when you want to move your mouse on Y axis.

I didn't find any code to use `/dev/input/mouse0`, so what information is saved in this file?

My questions are:

1. What information is saved in `/dev/input/mouse0`?
2. How can I read all mouse information without opening 2 files and without a priority problem (wheel scrolling + X/Y axis movement)?

Comment: Regarding your first snippet: the scroll wheel usually acts like buttons, one for each direction. If the first byte contains button states, you could check the remaining 5 bits. I bet two of them represent the scroll wheel.

Comment: just by using `cat /dev/input/mice`, there is nothing printed in the terminal when I use the scroll wheel

Comment: i've got nothing with `/dev/input/mouse0` too, probably I must use `/dev/input/event0` and try  to fix my code about the priority of X axis than Y axis

Comment: please consider accepting my answer if it helped you, or tell me why it didn't so I can improve it.

Comment: @danzel I didn't see the notification yesterday, your explaination is really good and do more than answer at my question, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Linux Input Subsystem userspace API documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/input/input_uapi.html) answers your questions. In general, all files in `/dev/input/` are provided by **event handlers** that distribute device events to userspace.

### What are /dev/input/mouse0 and /dev/input/mice?

From the [introduction](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/input/input.html) (important parts highlighted by me)

> **1.3.1.3. mousedev**
>
> mousedev is a hack to make legacy programs that use mouse input work. It takes events from either mice or
>   digitizers/tablets and makes a PS/2-style (a la /dev/psaux) mouse
>   device available to the userland.
>
> Mousedev devices in /dev/input (as shown above) are:
>
> ```
> crw-r--r--   1 root     root      13,  32 Mar 28 22:45 mouse0
> crw-r--r--   1 root     root      13,  33 Mar 29 00:41 mouse1
> crw-r--r--   1 root     root      13,  34 Mar 29 00:41 mouse2
> crw-r--r--   1 root     root      13,  35 Apr  1 10:50 mouse3 ... 
> ...
> crw-r--r--   1 root     root      13,  62 Apr  1 10:50 mouse30
> crw-r--r--   1 root     root      13,  63 Apr  1 10:50 mice
> ```
>
> **Each mouse
>   device is assigned to a single mouse or digitizer, except the last one
>   - mice. This single character device is shared by all mice and digitizers**, and even if none are connected, the device is present.
>   This is useful for hotplugging USB mice, so that older programs that
>   do not handle hotplug can open the device even when no mice are
>   present.
>   [...]
>
> Mousedev will generate either PS/2, ImPS/2 (Microsoft IntelliMouse) or ExplorerPS/2 (IntelliMouse Explorer) protocols, depending on what the program reading the data wishes. You can set GPM and X to any of these. **You’ll need ImPS/2 if you want to make use of a wheel on a USB mouse** and ExplorerPS/2 if you want to use extra (up to 5) buttons.

...this could also be reason why you don't see mouse wheel events. Since it is "a hack" for legacy programs, you shouldn't use it if you don't have to.

### How can I read all mouse information [...]?

Use the corresponding `/dev/input/eventX` file which is provided by **evdev** (the event handler, not to be confused with the xorg-driver evdev). That's what your second code snippet obviously does.

### ...but what about the priority problem?

There is no priority problem. According to [2.2. Event codes](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/input/event-codes.html#event-codes):

> SYN_REPORT:
>
> Used to synchronize and separate events into packets of
>   input data changes **occurring at the same moment in time**. For example,
>   motion of a mouse may set the REL_X and REL_Y values for one motion,
>   then emit a SYN_REPORT. The next motion will emit more REL_X and REL_Y
>   values and send another SYN_REPORT.

Because all consecutive events until a `SYN_REPORT` event can be considered to have happened at the same time, the order in which they are reported doesn't matter.

For example (using [this program](https://gist.github.com/uobikiemukot/457338b890e96babf60b) I found on github):

```
time:1528290186.256449  type:EV_REL     code:REL_X      value:-1
time:1528290186.256449  type:EV_REL     code:REL_Y      value:1
time:1528290186.256449  type:EV_SYN     code:SYN_REPORT value:0
time:1528290186.264460  type:EV_REL     code:REL_Y      value:1
time:1528290186.264460  type:EV_REL     code:REL_WHEEL  value:-1
time:1528290186.264460  type:EV_SYN     code:SYN_REPORT value:0
```

As you can see, not only are concurrent events separated by `SYN_REPORT` events, they also have the same time stamp.

By the way, you can also use `evtest` to see the events generated by a device. You can find its source code [here](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/evtest/tree/evtest.c) if you are interested in how it works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case have try to execute mouse event of OS.
my code in `app.js` was :

```
var Mouse = require("./node_modules/node-mouse/mouse");
 
var m = new Mouse();
 
m.on("mousedown",function(event) {
    console.log(event);
});
 
m.on("mouseup",function(event) {
    console.log(event);
});
 
// same as mouseup, but fired after
m.on("click",function(event) {
    console.log(event);
});
 
 
m.on("mousemove", function(event) {
    console.log(event);
});
```

i was running `node app.js`

so its giving me following error

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/dev/input/mice'
Emitted 'error' event on Mouse instance at:
```

so simply run with `sudo`  like that

`node app.js`

not its giving following error

```
{
  leftBtn: false,
  rightBtn: false,
  middleBtn: false,
  xSign: false,
  ySign: false,
  xOverflow: false,
  yOverflow: false,
  xDelta: 0,
  yDelta: 0,
  type: 'click',
  button: 1,
  dev: 'mice'
}
{
  leftBtn: false,
  rightBtn: false,
  middleBtn: false,
  xSign: false,
  ySign: false,
  xOverflow: false,
  yOverflow: false,
  xDelta: 0,
  yDelta: 0,
  type: 'click',
  button: 0,
  dev: 'mice'
}
{
  leftBtn: false,
  rightBtn: false,
  middleBtn: false,
  xSign: false,
  ySign: false,
  xOverflow: false,
  yOverflow: false,
  xDelta: 0,
  yDelta: 0,
  type: 'click',
  button: 0,
  dev: 'mice'
}
```