# Ubuntu 18.04 mouse not working after login

Tags: usb, mouse

I switched from Windows to Ubuntu and the mouse is not working. I tried 2 other mouses and the problem remains. So I think there is not a problem in the mouse.

The mouse is working on login screen. When I log into Ubuntu, the mouse stops working. I tried to upgrade `xserver-xorg-input-all` but it didnt help.

The mouse is detected by `lsusb` and the lights on the mouse are on, but only in USB3.0 port. When I connect the mouse into USB2.0, the mouse is not detected by `lsusb` and the lights are off.

Comment: Does your mouse work on Windows on USB2.0? If not, that's not a software issue but your USB2.0 is dead; about USB3.0, just do `sudo cat /dev/input/mice`; if nothing is prompt into your terminal, so there is an issue with your driver. You would find more information about this file on this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1044153/829702)

Comment: when I say nothing, it's when you re moving the mouse, terminal prompt nothing; use **Ctrl** + **C** to stop watching that file